# FlatList don't render images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got a problem with FlatList, I'm trying to render images with data I get from a database. But nothing is showing up. I can see the data from console, as you can see here:

[image]

But when I try o access *photo* it gives me two errors:

1. TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined
2. Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Right now I don't know why it's giving undefined, and the second error I have no clue about it.

This is my request to the backend:

```js
    loadGames = async () => {
        const response = await api.get("/games")

        const  { games }  = response.data
        console.log(games)
        this.setState({ games })
    }
```

I make the request as soon as the component mounts, so:

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadGames();
        this.loadPlayers();
        console.log(this.state.games)     
    }
```

I've declared the state:

```js
    state = {
        games:[],
        teams:[],
        players:[]
    }
```

Now the FlatList:

```
<View style={{ height: 130, marginTop: 20, justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <FlatList
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={this.state.games}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderGames(item)}
     />
</View>
```

The method that I call in `renderItem`:

```
renderGames = ({ item }) => {
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1/3, aspectRatio:1}} >
            <Image source={{ uri: `./image/games/${item.photo}` }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
}
```

Anyone know where I'm doing wrong? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Your `renderGames` function isn't actually returning anything.

```
renderGames = ({ item }) => (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1/3, aspectRatio:1}} >
            <Image source={{ uri: `./image/games/${item.photo}` }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
```

Should work.

Also, you should pass that function in to the `renderItem` prop, rather than creating your own arrow function, since you're passing in `item` as an argument, but then destructuring another `item` prop off of it:

```
renderItem={this.renderGames}
```

Comment: The errors stopped. But nothing shows up. Myabe it can be the image extension? Does React Native has a problem redering .ico?

Comment: It cannot render .ico

Comment: See the documentation for React Native's [image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images) component.  You can't use a relative path as a uri.  You can ```require``` the image if it's a static file on your back end, or pass a full URL.  And, as others of stated, an ico won't work

Comment: How do I use the require? My images are stored in the backend root. I read that `express` can pass a folder using `express.static`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: There are numerous examples in the link I posted: ```<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your `renderGames()` function not returning anything like @RutherfordWonkington mentioned, the React Native Image component does not accept `.ico` (windows icon) files.

> The currently supported formats are png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp (Android only), psd (iOS only)
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#source